# How to pass props to third-party component?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, prop

I'm trying to get [bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker](https://github.com/bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker) to work in English.

Thus, I need to pass a prop called: `i18n` and give it a value of `EN`.

This is what I did in Orders.vue:

```
<rangedate-picker :props="props" @selected="onSelect"></rangedate-picker>
```

And, this is what I did in VueJS code:

```
import VueRangedatePicker from 'vue-rangedate-picker';
export default {
    props: {
        'i18n': 'us/en',
    },

    components: {
        'rangedate-picker': VueRangedatePicker
    },

    data() {
        return {
            endpoint: '/approve',
            orders: [],
```

But I receive this error:

> dash.66983ac….js:52014 [Vue warn]: Property or method "props" is not
> defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that
> this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for
> class-based components, by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at C:\Users\bnbih\Projects\business2\api\resources\assets\js\components\orders.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass as `i18n`, not `props`

```
<rangedate-picker :i18n="language" @selected="onSelect"></rangedate-picker>
data() {
  return {
    language: 'en',
    endpoint: '/approve',
    orders: []
  }
}
```

Comment: I now receive this weird error: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined"

found in

---> <VueRangedatePicker> at src/RangedatePicker.vue
       <Orders> at C:\Users\bnbih\Projects\business2\api\resources\assets\js\components\orders.vue
         <Root>

Comment: never mind, the value for english seems to be EN not en. It works now!